# Django error in test only: django.contrib.auth.models.User.customers.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no customers

Tags: django, unit-testing

EDIT 21/01/2021

As mentionned in my last comment, error is link to the post_save signal when creating a User that create a Customers. But this is the right way to create a User with OneToOne models. I just change the name (update_user_customers -> create_user_cutomers that is more exact) and suppress the instance save that is not usefull here.

Morevover, I do not understand why the data migration works (exact same code to create my adin user) but not in tests.

If run test now, I got an IntegrityError for Customers_user_id_key.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Created
Not Created
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_users (cafe.tests.CafeTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: ERREUR:  la valeur d'une clé dupliquée rompt la contrainte unique « Customers_user_id_key »
DETAIL:  La clé « (user_id)=(3) » existe déjà.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DOCKER\Apps\cafe_tropical\app\cafe\tests.py", line 32, in setUp
    Customers.objects.create(
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\safedelete\models.py", line 97, in save
    super(SafeDeleteModel, self).save(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 740, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 777, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 907, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1335, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ERREUR:  la valeur d'une clé dupliquée rompt la contrainte unique « Customers_user_id_key »
DETAIL:  La clé « (user_id)=(3) » existe déjà.
```

---

EDIT 2

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_customers(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):    <- change name
    if created:
        Customers.objects.create(user=instance)
    # instance.customers.save()                                    <- line deactivate
```

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.5 on 2020-12-16 08:56

from django.db import migrations
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django.apps import apps as configured_apps
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions

from randomuser import RandomUser
import random
import datetime
from faker import Faker
import pytz


import requests

# create menus (food and drinks)
# API thecocktaildb.coml
# API api.spoonacular.com
def create_menus(apps, schema_editor):
    # response = requests.get('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Cocktail')
    # # transform the response to json objects
    # cocktails = response.json()

    # cocktails = requests.get('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Cocktail').json()['drinks'][i]['strDrink']
    # dishes = requests.get('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?number=10&cuisine=American&type=main course&apiKey=2e9e2e2925e243f484364f78679112fc').json()['recipes'][i]['title']
    Menus = apps.get_model('cafe', 'Menus')
    cocktails = requests.get('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Cocktail').json()['drinks'][:10]
    dishes = requests.get('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?number=10&cuisine=American&type=main course&apiKey=2e9e2e2925e243f484364f78679112fc').json()['recipes'][:10]

    for i in range(10):

        Menus.objects.create(
            item = cocktails[i]['strDrink'],
            price = round(random.uniform(2.00,10.00),2),
            last_order_date = timezone.now(),
            conservation = random.randrange(5,15),
            available = True,
            created_at = timezone.now()
        )
        Menus.objects.create(
            item = dishes[i]['title'],
            price = round(random.uniform(5.00,10.00),2),
            last_order_date = timezone.now(),
            conservation = random.randrange(5,15),
            available = True,
            created_at = timezone.now()
        )

def create_app_users(apps, schema_editor):
    
    User = apps.get_model(*settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.'))
    Customers = apps.get_model('cafe', 'Customers')

    # user admin
    User.objects.create(
        username = 'admin',
        is_superuser = True,
        is_staff = True,
        email = 'jerome.le-carrou@u-bordeaux.fr',
        password = 'pbkdf2_sha256$150000$qe1v2XJKkik8$jF6iFZ+4GpK1JzBdHzRG0H3XsYY+YphYpxc9Cbgg+7Y=',
        date_joined = timezone.now()
    )
    Customers.objects.create(
        user = User.objects.get(username='admin'),
        customer_type = 1,
        created_at = timezone.now()
    )

    
    User.objects.create(
        username = 'twyla',
        first_name = 'Sands',
        last_name ='Twyla',
        email = 'twyla.sands@example.com',
        password = 'pbkdf2_sha256$150000$qQLXtfRCoMiw$w3OHPMWaU+Xd2oihppp5DQbmZdmAx56KbNvJrrJxKj4=',
        date_joined = timezone.now()
    )
    Customers.objects.create(
        user = User.objects.get(username='twyla'),
        customer_type = 2,
        created_at = timezone.now()
    )


# create 10000 randomly users/customers (randomuser.me)
def create_users(apps, schema_editor):
    
    User = apps.get_model(*settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.'))
    Customers = apps.get_model('cafe', 'Customers')

    # Rose's familly members: Davis Rose, Alexis Rose, Moira Rose
    User.objects.create(
        username = 'david.rose',
        first_name = 'Rose',
        last_name ='David',
        email = 'david.rose@example.com',
        password = 'pbkdf2_sha256$150000$qQLXtfRCoMiw$w3OHPMWaU+Xd2oihppp5DQbmZdmAx56KbNvJrrJxKj4=',
        date_joined = timezone.now()
    )
    Customers.objects.create(
        user = User.objects.get(username='david.rose'),
        customer_type = 3,
        drink_preferences = 1,
        food_preferences = 1,
        created_at = timezone.now()
    )

    User.objects.create(
        username = 'alexis.rose',
        first_name = 'Rose',
        last_name ='Alexis',
        email = 'alexis.rose@example.com',
        password = 'pbkdf2_sha256$150000$qQLXtfRCoMiw$w3OHPMWaU+Xd2oihppp5DQbmZdmAx56KbNvJrrJxKj4=',
        date_joined = timezone.now()
    )
    Customers.objects.create(
        user = User.objects.get(username='alexis.rose'),
        customer_type = 3,
        drink_preferences = 1,
        food_preferences = 2,
        created_at = timezone.now()
    )

    User.objects.create(
        username = 'moira.rose',
        first_name = 'Rose',
        last_name ='Moira',
        email = 'moira.rose@example.com',
        password = 'pbkdf2_sha256$150000$qQLXtfRCoMiw$w3OHPMWaU+Xd2oihppp5DQbmZdmAx56KbNvJrrJxKj4=',
        date_joined = timezone.now()
    )
    Customers.objects.create(
        user = User.objects.get(username='moira.rose'),
        customer_type = 3,
        drink_preferences = 2,
        food_preferences = 1,
        created_at = timezone.now()
    )

    # Generate a list of 10000 random users
    # RandomUser only allowed to generate 5000 at a time: I call 2 time the API to get the 10000
    
    try:
        users1 = RandomUser.generate_users(5000)
        for user in users1:
            u = User.objects.create(
                username = user.get_username()+str(random.randrange(100000)),
                first_name = user.get_first_name(),
                last_name = user.get_last_name(),
                email = user.get_email(),
                password = 'pbkdf2_sha256$150000$qQLXtfRCoMiw$w3OHPMWaU+Xd2oihppp5DQbmZdmAx56KbNvJrrJxKj4=',
                date_joined = timezone.now()
            )
            Customers.objects.create(
                user = u,
                customer_type = 1,
                drink_preferences = 1,
                food_preferences = 1,
                created_at = timezone.now()
            )
        users2 = RandomUser.generate_users(4994)
        for user in users2:
            u = User.objects.create(
                username = user.get_username()[::-1]+str(random.randrange(100000)),
                first_name = user.get_first_name(),
                last_name = user.get_last_name(),
                email = user.get_email(),
                password = 'pbkdf2_sha256$150000$qQLXtfRCoMiw$w3OHPMWaU+Xd2oihppp5DQbmZdmAx56KbNvJrrJxKj4=',
                date_joined = timezone.now()
            )
            Customers.objects.create(
                user = u,
                customer_type = 1,
                drink_preferences = 1,
                food_preferences = 1,
                created_at = timezone.now()
            )
    except:
        print('error')

# create orders associated to customers
def create_orders(apps, schema_editor):
    
    User = apps.get_model(*settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.'))
    Orders = apps.get_model('cafe', 'Orders')
    Menus = apps.get_model('cafe', 'Menus')
    Tables = apps.get_model('cafe', 'Tables')
    Customers = apps.get_model('cafe', 'Customers')
    Customers_Orders_Comments = apps.get_model('cafe', 'Customers_Orders_Comments')

    users = [user.id for user in User.objects.all().exclude(id__lte=2)]
    menus = [menu.menu_id for menu in Menus.objects.all()]
    tables = [table for table in Tables.objects.all()]

    # fake random date using faker
    fake = Faker()

    # STEP 1
    # loop over the 10000 customers to determine how many orders they did individually (randomly choosen beetween 2 and 14)
    # save in a list of tuples: individuals_orders = [(customer_id,number),]
    # and how many orders in total for the 10000 customers
    individuals_orders = []
    total_orders = 0
    for customer in Customers.objects.all().exclude(customer_id = User.objects.get(username='twyla').id):
        n = random.randrange(2,14)
        individuals_orders.append((customer.customer_id,n))
        total_orders += n

    # STEP 2    
    # loop over the range of total_orders to create Orders
    for order in range(0,total_orders + 1):
        o = Orders.objects.create(
            table = random.sample(tables,k=1)[0],
            customers = random.randrange(1,6),
            split_bill = random.randrange(1,3),
            delivered = True,
            paid = True,
        )
        o.created_at = fake.date_time_between(start_date='now', end_date='+2y', tzinfo=pytz.utc)
        o.save()
        # Orders.objects.filter(order_id = o.order_id).update(created_at = fake.date_time_between(start_date='now', end_date='+2y'))

    
    # STEP 3
    # 'link' Customers to Orders (model Customers_Orders_Comments)
    for customer in individuals_orders:
        for i in range(1,customer[1]):
            Customers_Orders_Comments.objects.create(
                order_id = random.randrange(1,total_orders),
                customer_id = customer[0]
            )

    # to control algorithme:
    # - SELECT customer_id,count(*) FROM "Customers_Orders_Comments" GROUP BY customer_id ORDER BY customer_id;
    # - SELECT max(created_at) FROM "Orders"; SELECT min(created_at) FROM "Orders";

# https://dummyapi.io/account (j.lecarrou@gmail.com)
# API user with post and comments
# via postman : 
# Headers: app-id 60016315253f3585ce4251a7
# url list of posts: https://dummyapi.io/data/api/post/ (with id - e.g. VGyIwGVWeeurHv5bSZgx)
# url comment for a given post: https://dummyapi.io/data/api/post/{postId}/comment
def get_id_comments():
    id = []
    url = 'https://dummyapi.io/data/api/post/'
    headers = {'app-id': '60016315253f3585ce4251a7'}     
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    for i in data['data']:
        # print(i['id']) # return all id 
        id.append(i['id'])
    return id

def create_comments(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model(*settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.'))
    Comments = apps.get_model('cafe', 'Comments')
    ids = get_id_comments()

    headers = {'app-id': '60016315253f3585ce4251a7'}     

    for i in range(0,len(ids)):
        url = 'https://dummyapi.io/data/api/post/'+ids[i]+'/comment'
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        data = response.json()
        if data['data']:                                  
            # print(data['data'][0]['message'])
            Comments.objects.create(
                title = 'Wonderfull place!',
                comment = data['data'][0]['message'],
                rate = random.randrange(1,3), #defined number of colored stars
                like = random.randrange(1,100),
                dislike = random.randrange(1,100),
                created_at = timezone.now()
            )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('cafe', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql = [
                'INSERT INTO "Tables" (number,available,created_at) VALUES (6,True,Now());',
                'INSERT INTO "Tables" (number,available,created_at) VALUES (4,True,Now());',
                'INSERT INTO "Tables" (number,available,created_at) VALUES (4,True,Now());',
                'INSERT INTO "Tables" (number,available,created_at) VALUES (2,True,Now());',
            ]
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(create_app_users),
        # migrations.RunPython(create_users),
        # migrations.RunPython(create_orders),
        migrations.RunPython(create_menus),
        # migrations.RunPython(create_comments),
    ]
```

---

EDIT

```
 py manage.py test cafe.tests.CafeTestCase --settings=core.settings._test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Created
Not Created
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_users (cafe.tests.CafeTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DOCKER\Apps\cafe_tropical\app\cafe\tests.py", line 32, in setUp
    u.save()
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 740, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 788, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DOCKER\Apps\cafe_tropical\app\parameters\models.py", line 34, in email_new_user
    instance.save()
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 788, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DOCKER\Apps\cafe_tropical\app\cafe\models.py", line 141, in update_user_customers
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\Envs\envIntensecovAPI\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 412, in __get__
    raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
django.contrib.auth.models.User.customers.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no customers.
```

I write test in Django.

But for a reason I can't explain, some code that use to work in data migration does not work in tests.

I have two models related with a oneToOne relationship: User and Customers.

I create Users first and Customers 'based' on Users created just before.

Here I use RandomUser API but even if I create User and Customers 'normally' it failed

In my tests.py:

```
class CafeTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
    
        users1 = RandomUser.generate_users(5)
        for user in users1:
            u = User.objects.create(
                username = user.get_username()+str(random.randrange(100000)),
                ...
                date_joined = timezone.now()
            )
            Customers.objects.create(
                user = u,
                ...
                created_at = timezone.now()
            )
```

Comment: Share your error logs so we can better understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Do all of your `users` have at least one customer created in the test case? It looks like Django is complaining about a model method at line 141 where you attempting to do something with a user's `customers` when the user, in fact, has none. Remember that your test database is a brand new instance every time, and will retain no data from your development database.

Comment: 2 User with customers instance related are created by data migration and available in test database

Comment: @Mereva hmm only 2 out of the 5 that you create in the test case have customers? and could you share the code for ```update_user_customers``` in the models as well?

Comment: the 2 user are created with data migrations, not in tests.py

Comment: Right, make sure that the test case creates the users that we need every single time. You will not be able to use any of the models that you created before the test is ran. The database is created anew each time the test is ran, and destroyed after. Make sure you are recreating all the model instances you need each time the test case runs. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database for more information. Consider your test database a brand new database every time the test runs.

Comment: you are right BUT the 2 users I talk about are created by the python migrate command when creating the test database ; if I print(User.objects.all()) during tests, the 2 users created by data migration are return...

Comment: Okay so 2 have customers, but we need all 5 of them to have customers for the model method to not throw an error. You are creating 5 users in the test case - ```users1 = RandomUser.generate_users(5)``` .OR you can just change the code in the method ```update_user_customers``` to handle a user model instance with no customers. Then this should be okay

Comment: not sure to understand: 2 users have Customers (from data migration). The 5 I create in test need a Customers but that's exactly what I do. I create user with API and use theses data to effectively create User. In the same loop, for each User, I create a Customers...

Comment: So, I've try a thing: I deactivate update_user_customers post_save method and test succeeded